# Symfony2 Twig and Controller cache

Tags: symfony, caching, controller, twig

I have a problem with environments about cache.

When I modified a Twig, I view this modification on DEV and I need clear cache for see this change on Prod. This is correct.

But when I modified a Controller, I view this modification on DEV and on PROD too, without clear cache.

I have this configuration on files:

app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

app_dev.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Comment: before symfony 2.4, when i modified controller and twig, changes not view on production until i clear cache. I don't understand why change this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **symfony 2.4+** with **Sensio Framework 3.0+** you can try to set your caching policy directly on your controllers via `@cache` annotation as follows:

<kbd>**YourController**</kbd>

```php
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Cache;
/**
 * @Cache(expires="tomorrow", public="true")
 */
 class YourController extends Controller
 {
   /**
    * @Cache(expires="+2 days")
    */
    public function yourAction() {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can manage the [cache attributes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/cache.html#attributes) that suite your needs. As far as I know the caching policy for controllers could not be completely disabled for the prod env.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using DEV environment guarantees you that your modifications will be applied immediately. That if something was cached and you've made some changes in these cached files then the cache will be regenerated without additional actions.

I.e. using DEV environment just exempts you from the necessity of running cache:clear after every change of your code, that's all.

But it doesn't mean that **all the code** is cached and you may make any changes in the code on PROD. You **may not** rely on a cache and expect that changes will not take place until you regenerate the cache.

Controllers usually are not cached at all, so of course all your modifications in controllers on prod will be seen instantly.